# Print(real time) value of option

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, font-awesome

I want to print icon(font awesome) into "input-group" from option tag.(look at picture)
[image]

This is my code:

```
echo '<label for="icon">Icon (Font Awesome)</label>';
echo '<div class="input-group col-xs-4">';
echo '<span class="input-group-addon" id="3"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> </span>';
echo '<select name="icon" class="form-control" aria-describedby="3">';
echo '<option value="home">home</option>';
.....
echo '</select>';
```

So I need, somehow, change this class="fa fa-***home***" depending on selected option value. Can you help me? I want to change it without refreshing the site and so on.

Comment: onchange, change the class.

Comment: If I was able to do it, I would not write here.

Comment: Do you know how to attach an onchange event to an element?

Comment: Never used jQuery or JS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can add an event listener to your "select" tag :

```
$("select[name='icon']").on('change', function() {
  $("#3").find("i").prop("class", "fa fa-" + $(this).val());
});
```